# Forgive someone who is right?

Tags: meaning

Can I use the word "forgive" to mean to stop being resentful towards someone who has done something right even though I am upset about it? if not, what is the appropriate word to use?

Comment: Isn't that word in your language? You ask them to forgive you.

Comment: No, you can't. The other person has not wronged you, so there is nothing to forgive. Please look this word up in a dictionary.